# Will the pod IP change without the pod being recreated

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, coredns

I need a way to directly talk to a pod from another pod within the same namespace. When a pod is starting the IP details will be sent to the second pod. So as long as it doesn't change without the pod being recreated I'm good. So my question would be, will the Pod's IP change without pod being recreated.

PS: I'm trying to avoid Statefulsets for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less chances there without **re-create**, However few chances when **IP** gets changed which you can not control.

- Node failed or Rescheduling
- Network changes

The best option is to use the **statefulset** but you mentioned you not inclined toward it.

If you just using POD without any controller like Deployment you can use the **Hostname & Subdomain** in the spec section.

```
spec:
  hostname: pod-data
  subdomain: data-subdomain
```

Which you can resolve in another POD, however, if you use it in **Deployment** it will work but it's better to use **service**. As the **hostname** will be the same across all **replicas** of deployment.

i am not able to understand actually the requirement to use **POD IP**, you can keep **single** replicas of POD handled by **deployment** backed by **service**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At a very high-level, what I have is something like a Health Monitor Dashboard. So Dashboard should connect to each pod and check it's health. And at the moment I have a Deployment controlling the pods. Few questions, 
1. Node failure would again result in pod recreation right? 
2. What type of network changes that can happen for IPs to change?
3. My app doesn't really maintain a state, so that's why I'm don't really want to use Statefulsets just for the health checks etc. Is here any other way like using a headleass service with deployments to do this?

Comment: You can use a `headless service` no doubt, it will return the `POD's` IP that is associated to svc. But as you mentioned you are focusing on IP not being change for POD, if you are fine with headless it will return IP of POD even if get changed after a crash or recreate. You can use service name as hostname would be better than using IP of POD which is not static.

Comment: With a headless service can I use a DNS like, `podname.servicename.namespace` to connect? If not I assume when I do a HTTP request to a headless service it still delivers the message in a round-robbing manner to pods? What I understand is Headless service just returns the IPs so you need to handle this in the client side if you want to connect to individual pods, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Podname dns only possible with statefulset i guess. But you can use svc name. Correct it will return the IPs only you have to handle it client side.